# Is it possible to store a music file in iPhone local storage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making an iPhone app in which the user can listen to some stories which are present on my web server.

Now I want to download that audio story file to local iPhone memory on download button click.

I am successfully downloading the file from the webserver but the file is saving somewhere else, not in phone memory. Any one know how I can store the file in iPhone memory, not in application document memory?

Answer (score 0):

I think links will help you to get some idea about document directory

[link1](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files%22link1%22)

[link 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

here is the some sample code snippet

```
NSString *filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.caf"];
[fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES ];

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: is this code save my file directly to iphone memory same as u download some music file from itunes and it will save in iphone music folder??

Comment: no it is not possible to add music file to iPhone music library,you can only save in our application directory and you can use that file from there

Comment: but i want to store it in my iphone music library same as in case of what's app